# WPF MVVM check for updates, notify user, shutdown application, install updates, restart application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm looking for a way of checking for updated, for example every 5min, and if update is available, notify a user about the update, shutdown application, install updates and restart application. I was looking everywhere, but can't find any proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Easy Way**

[ClickOnce Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx) As already suggested

**The Hard Way**

For this, you will need:

- A server exposing any API you can use to get the latest version (eg. simple linux running apache2 and a plain text file containing a version number and a link)
- Code to *Download* the new binary
- Code to *Install* the update (Either doing it yourself (keep in mind you might need admin rights for theese things) or using a setup exe)

The server part is obviously your stuff, but the file could look like this:

```
 1.2.456.78:http://MyServer.tl/path/to/binary.ext
```

Now to get this file, use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(@"http://MyServer.tl/path/to/version.info"))
{
    [Code handling the version info file]
}
```

now you can compare your current binary version with the latest version

```
var extractedVersion = Version.Parse(extractedNewVersionString)
var currentVersion = typeof(AnyTypeInYourExeProject).Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
if (extractedVersion > currentVersion)
{
    [Continue with downloading]
}
```

After you confirmed you are out of date, simply display the client in any way you like (try to avoid message boxes as that just annoys a lot of users)

When you then want to download the update, again use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

```
//exeurl contains our updated executable url
//downloadTo is where we want the executable to be downloaded to
//prog is a progress reporter allowing you to keep track of current progress
public static async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(string exeurl, string downloadTo, IProgress<Tuple<long, long>> prog)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //Create new client
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        //Await the Get Response
        //HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead allows us to process the headers before we actually
        //Download the file
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(info.link, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        //Get the content
        using (var responseContent = response.Content)
        {
            //Make sure that the directory exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(downloadTo)))
            {
                //Create if it does not
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(downloadTo));
            }
            //A variable to allow us to report current progress
            long curLen = 0;
            //Now create the file
            using (var fStream = File.Create(downloadTo))
            //And start reading the stream async
            using (var hStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                //and get into a simple loop
                while (true)
                {
                    //Create a buffer to read the bytes in chunks from the stream
                    //(256 is just some example size, can be of any size you like)
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    var readBytes = hStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    //if no bytes have been read, we are done
                    if (readBytes == 0)
                        break;
                    //write the buffer to the file
                    fStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    //append the ammount of read bytes to our current progress variable
                    curLen += readBytes;
                    //and report the progress to the callee
                    //responseContent.Headers.ContentLength.Value btw. contains the ContentLength reported by the server
                    prog.Report(new Tuple<long, long>(curLen, responseContent.Headers.ContentLength.Value));
                }
            }
            return downloadTo;
        }
    });
}
```

Afterwards you have to simply start the setup executable or a console that requests admin rights upon start (alt. use a separate executable instead)

hope i could help

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like this is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ClickOnce Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx) to achieve this.